# Why does smartmatch return false when I match against a regex containing slashes?

Tags: regex, perl, smartmatch

I'm trying to match a simple string against a regular expression pattern using the smartmatch operator:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use open qw(:std :utf8);

my $name = qr{/(\w+)/};
my $line = 'string';

print "ok\n" if $line ~~ /$name/;
```

I expect this to print "ok", but it doesn't. Why not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove the slashes from your regex:

```
my $name = qr{(\w+)};
```

Since you're wrapping the regular expression in `qr{}`, everything inside the braces is being interpreted as the regular expression. Therefore, if you were to expand out your search, it'd be:

```
print "ok\n" if $line ~~ /\/(\w+)\//;
```

Since your string doesn't start or end with slashes (or have any substrings that do), then the match fails, and you don't print `ok`.